# How to host a static blog through Pelican on Github

Tags: python, github, pelican

I am trying to generate a static blog through Pelican and then host it on GitHub.

I have no problem generating a blog locally, but I struggle when I try to push it to GitHub. I have scoured the web looking for instruction, but it seems like the authors skip steps that would be trivial to someone with experience, but not to a beginner.

Could anyone provide a step-by-step guide on how to host a static blog generated with Pelican on GitHub?

Comment: there is a best way to do that regarding the official documentation. There is no need of an hold.

Answer (score 4):

Considering you want to push it on your user repository:

To publish a Pelican site in the form of User Pages, you need to push the content of the output dir generated by Pelican to the master branch of your .github.io repository on GitHub.

You can take advantage of ghp-import:

```
$ pelican content -o output -s pelicanconf.py
$ ghp-import output
$ git push git@github.com:elemoine/elemoine.github.io.git gh-pages:master
```

The git push command pushes the local gh-pages branch (freshly updated by the ghp-import command) to the elemoine.github.io repository’s master branch on GitHub.

Myself I use a one liner doing the same:

```
$pelican && ghp-import output && git push git@github.com:maggick/maggick.github.io.git gh-pages:master
```

(source: http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/tips.html)